# SPI on Beagleboard Black

Tags: beagleboneblack, spi

I've been trying to make the serial communication work on my BBB for days now and I am running out of ideas.

When I use just the BBB and connect MISO/MOSI I get the signal transfer on MOSI, SCLK and CS (MISO is mainly at high level). However, when I connect the lines to my slave part it does not work. I checked the signals on the oscilloscope and they seem fine and the part which I am using as the slave is working well when I set it in parallel mode, so I believe some programming or configuration must be wrong.

This is basically what I do:

config-pin P9.17 spi_cs

config-pin P9.18 spi

config-pin P9.21 spi

config-pin P9.22 spi_sclk

python

```
from Adafruit_BBIO.SPI import SPI
spi = SPI(1,0) #I would expect SPI(0,0) here, but I get the signal on the above configured ports
```

Then I set the configurations (already tried in many ways):

```
spi.mode = 0
spi.cshigh = False
spi.msh = 10500000
spi.bpw = 16
spi.lsbfirst = False
```

After that I open it and try to send data:

```
spi.open(1,0)
spi.xfer2([1,254])
```

If anyone is interested, I am trying to program the LMH6517 as slave and I already tried to ask about this at the TI forum here:
https://e2e.ti.com/support/amplifiers/f/14/t/751415

Oscilloscope images:

[CS and SCLK](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tNppG.png)

[MOSI and SCLK](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bv3cT.png)

[MISO and SCLK](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xplub.jpg)

Thank you,

JPL

Comment: Just to confirm: You have checked MISO line with an oscilloscope, and it's looks fine? Are you sure? That would mean receive part of your software doesn't work correctly, or there's possibly some clock issue. Please also describe what does "it does not work" mean for you (invalid data in reply, all 0, all 0xff, something else).

Comment: I checked the MOSI line because from the MISO side I get all 0xff (the LMH6517 has a pull-up resistor on the MISO which I removed already just to test). I tried reducing the clock too but got no results. The datasheet of the LMH6517 says 10.5MHz, so I tried that one and also slower clocks like 100kHz or 1MHz. What I mean by it does not work is that I cannot program the register, because I am supposed to get an output from the LMH6517 according to what is set there, but my output is not varying.

Comment: Please include this in original post. It's very much relevant that MOSI looks fine, but MISO is always high. This suggests something might be wrong on the LMH6517 side. How do SCLK and CS look like? What about other pins of LMH6517? What are the exact commands that you send and what reply is expected for those? What's your exact code (SPI does TX and RX at the same time, so you need to "transmit" dummy bytes to receive a response; that doesn't appear to be the case in incomplete excerpts above)?

Comment: You are right, I included it on the main post. I have a modified evaluation board here for the LMH6517 that works for the other operation modes (parallel and pulse)´, but not for SPI. That is why I think the chip itself might be alright. SCLK and CS seem fine, but for higher frequencies, the clock looks distorted a bit (it could be due to the oscilloscope probe or wires). When I test it with the beagleboard alone and connect its MISO/MOSI, I get the response I sent.

Comment: Just adding some info to my last comment: The LMH6517 is a programmable gain amplifier, so I would expect to change the gain as I program a new one there, but it is kept always at the same gain. And when I try to read, I get all ones. The message I send should have 16 bits (if you have the time you can see it here http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lmh6517.pdf on page  20).

Comment: Is the code in question the code you are using? It is very much incomplete. I also can't find 254/0xfe/0b11111110 matching command in the datasheet (does not fit into r/w 0 0 0 a3 a2 a1 a0).

Comment: Yes, but I don't have much python experience so I wonder if it is correct. I could not find much info online (some places I checked are like this https://adafruit-beaglebone-io-python.readthedocs.io/en/latest/SPI.html#module-Adafruit_BBIO.SPI or posts like this https://github.com/adafruit/adafruit-beaglebone-io-python/issues/166). From what I understood, if I want to program a maximum gain on channel B, I should send 00000001 11111110, so I would send for example spi.xfer2([1,254]), I also tried different values and inverting to see if it would change anything.

Comment: I included the oscilloscope images in the question, maybe it helps. I send spi.xfer2([1,254]) there.

Comment: Are you sure that's `[1, 0xfe]` in MOSI trace and not `[0xfe, 1]`? What would you expect on MISO in this case (I think 0xff makes sense)? I think you should send a read command and a dummy write bytes to get something on MISO. The github issue you reference doesn't get any data in loopback mode. Have you tried just putting a resistor between MISO and MOSI and checking SPI works fine without slave? Code in your question is still very much incomplete.

Comment: I am not sure what the LMH6517 would send me back when I program it, but I would expect the gain to change if I changed the register value and that does not happen. When I connect MISO and MOSI together just with the beagleboard I get my signal there as a response, so it seems to work. I also thought that the voltage level could be wrong (in the pictures you can see that ch1 and ch2 are using different V/div), but it was just a probe issue.

Comment: Does the *code* work with loopback setup?

Comment: I believe it does because when I send something and the MISO/MOSI of the beagleboard are connected I get it back.